# Quitting Body building or weight trainning

Tags: weightlifting, weights

If i quit body building . will my body fat increase considerably and become obese

Comment: Depends on the type of lifestyle you have after quitting, if you still have an active life, I don't think you'll put on a lot of weight, but you wont be buff either(since you quit exercising your muscles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you reduce your total amount of daily calories to your actual requirements and you still have an active life (not staying all day in home), you won't get fat.
There is a lot of people who don't practice any sport and are not fat at all.